# Using Aurelia-Datatable (from SpoonX)

Tags: aurelia

I'd like to use SpoonX's repo of Aurelia-Datatable.  I've already installed all the dependencies with `npm` and added them to `aurelia.json` (correctly, I believe).  Now I'm ready to actually use it.  But the [documentation](https://aurelia-datatable.spoonx.org/usage.html) doesn't show how to require or import the library.  I'd prefer to do it globally, and ensure compatibility with Bootstrap.

I've tried the following and they don't work.

```
import 'aurelia-datatable'; // (in my-viewmodel.js)

<require from="aurelia-datatable"></require> // (in my-view.html)
```

What is the proper way to use this repo?  The following tag is being completely ignored in my view.

```
<datatable resource="records" columns="user_username,user_password,p_fname,p_lname"></datatable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in loading the plugin in the `main.js`, which had not been very clear in the documentation.  The following line activated the library globally:

```
aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-datatable');
```